# How to create a suggestion box

Tags: java, swing

I was developing an java swing application to add view and modify the list of medicines.While adding the medicines it should show the list from the database(like google search box).For example if we press "p" it should show 'paracetamol' from the database.

Comment: Take a look at SwingLabs AutoComplete decorator

Comment: You may also want to check out the example at [How to use text areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) which might give you some ideas

Comment: it works.But I need text field.

Comment: And you can't expand the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a change listener on the text input box, when the text is changed, run a query to the database with the contents of the input box.

Comment: If only text components where that simple :P

Comment: Heh, alright so to elaborate a little bit, you could use the KeyListener interface, and to your text field add your own custom implementation of this interface. You could store the current content of the text box in a variable, and when a key is pressed, you compare the text in the box, to the text in the storage variable. If it is different, then the text has changed and you should call your database query method. You could also check how many characters in the box ie don't query the database unless 3 or more characters have been typed, to save excessive database calls.

Comment: In a text field, use `DocumentListener`, not `KeyListener`.

Comment: Let's not even get into the difficulties of updating the fields text as you type :P

Comment: Ah yeh forgot about that one :) And yeah it's a science in itself, but was just trying to give some simple ideas. Of course you have issues from every key press etc... Also yeah you could just use a library like MadProgrammer recommended :)